# What is this hexagonal board game with 10 marbles to a side?

Tags: identify-this-game

I saw this game at a friend's place but nobody knew what it was called. Google search and reverse image search didn't help.

[image]

This is a hexagonal board with:

- 10 white marbles
- 10 dark marbles
- 37 notches to put them in

Comment: It looks like a variant on the chinese checkers game but with only 2 sides: http://www.checkerschest.com/chinese-checkers/

Comment: possibly a dupe of http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/32688/1926?

Comment: On the first glance this reminds me of Abalone, but board size and number of marbles doesn't match.